# Java UDP Client Not Receiving Packets

Tags: java, udp, datagram, packets

I've made a java application which uses UDP and I can't seem to receive packets outside LAN when hosting on my computer. I tried putting my application on a Hosted Server and it seemed to work (receives packet).

What is causing this to happen? I want it to work on my computer as well.

CLIENT:

```
try {
    this.socket = new DatagramSocket(2500);
} catch (SocketException e1) {
    System.out.println("Could not establish connection");
    return;
}
while(true){
    byte[] data = new byte[1024];
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);

    try{
        socket.receive(packet);
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("Connection close");
        break;
    }
    System.out.println("RECEIVED " + new String(packet.getData()));
}
```

SERVER:

```
try {
    this.socket = new DatagramSocket(25860);
} catch (SocketException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    byte[] data = datas.getBytes();
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, ipAddress, 2500);

    socket.send(packet);
}catch(IOException e) {

}

System.out.println("Sent " + ipAddress.getHostAddress() + ":" + port + " " + new String(datas));
```

IP Address is correct, it exactly prints out the same IP as my CLIENT. However I'm still not receiving.

Comment: Don't print '"Could not establish connection' when you can't create a `DatagramSocket,` or 'connection close' when you get an `IOException` receiving a UDP datagram. Print the exception. There is no connection to establish or close in the first place, and in the second place you're suppressing vital debug information. And *never* ignore an IOException, as you are after `send()`. Fix that and adjust your question accordingly with what really happens. `new String(packet.getData()))` should be `new String(packet.getData(), packet.getOffset(), packet.getLength()))`.

Answer (score 0):

If it works in one computer (single) and not on the other try checking the firewall, UDP connections should be allowed in your computer.

Comment: Err, no. Have a look at the Javadoc. Constructing a `DatagramSocket` doesn't connect to anything, it *binds*, to a local IP address and port. This will throw a `BindException.`

Comment: You are right, however I read the post quickly the SERVER and CLIENT are misleading in the original question post. One would expect the client to connect to the server. However it could be part of wider communication sequence. Thanks to your remark I changed my answer to avoid having misleading answers.

Comment: I agree, client and server seem to be back to front in the question.